# In OpenGL ES 2.0 iOS5 template, the program work without the shaders. How come?

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I tried to rename the files in the project tree (Shader.vsh and Shader.fsh) to (Shader2.vsh and Shader2.fsh) and I was expecting it not to work, but it worked.

I renamed the file name inside ViewController.m to be:

```
vertShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"vsh"];
```

to be:

```
vertShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader2" ofType:@"vsh"];
```

And it doesn't work. It always work with the name Shader.vsh even if you renamed the file.

Moreover I tried to remove the file entirely, and it still works. It displays the two cubes. How come!!!

Comment: Sounds like some kind of caching problem. Tried cleaning your project and rebuilding?

Comment: Those original files might still be present in the application bundle. The renamed files might not be copied over into the new bundle, because Xcode often treats those as source code files and they sometimes need to be manually dragged into Copy Bundle Phases build phase.

Answer (score 1):

That is often a problem with Xcode. Files you remove or rename in your project will not be removed from the built app bundle if you just hit the run button.  This makes the build a little faster, but can lead to bizarre problems such as yours.

The solution, or actually just a workaround, is to clean your project after removing or renaming resources. It probably isn't necessary every time, but always worth a try if you are running into problems with resources.

Answer (score 0):

May be it uses GLKit that creates default shader.

Answer (score 0):

because in default template rendered with shders and GLKit.

You should remove GLKit code.

For example

```
    - (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
    {
        glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

        // Render the object with GLKit
        [self.effect prepareToDraw]; // GLKit used default shaders

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); // render with GLKit

        // Render the object again with ES2
        glUseProgram(_program);  // enable shader


// set parametres
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0, _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
        glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); // render with Sahder, because glUseProgram(_program);
    }
```

In setupGL you can found [self loadShaders];